# CSS Transformation causing scroll back/flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not completely sure how to explain what's going on. I'm trying to do a transformation on my search bar after it's submitted. The CSS and HTML are pretty large so I'm linking to CodePen to see in action, but I'll post the JS/CSS here as well.

I'd like to do something 'fancy' with the search bar, while the results pop up on the same screen so I thought 'transitions'.

**CSS**

```
.postSearch{
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
  -moz-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  margin-left: 80%;
}
```

**HTML Form**

```
 <div class="revolver">
        <form id="myForm">
            <p class="inp-wrap search-wrap">
                <label for="charName" class="search-label grid-25">Find</label>
                <input type="search" name="charName" id="charName" class="grid-75" placeholder="e.g. Teodoro" />
            </p>
            <p class="inp-wrap cat-wrap">
                <label for="servers" class="grid-20">on</label>
                <select name="servers" id="servers" class="grid-80">
                    <option>Thrall</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p class="inp-wrap submit-wrap">
                <button class="grid-100 btn" name="SubmitButton" onclick="updateTransition()" type="button">
                    <span class="search-icon-container">
          <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span> GO!
                </button>
            </p>
        </form>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
function updateTransition() {
  var el = document.querySelector("div.revolver");
  if (el) {
    $('#myForm').addClass('postponed');
    $('#myForm').removeClass('myForm');

    el.className = "postSearch";
  } else {
    $('#myForm').addClass('myForm');
    $('#myForm').removeClass('postponed');
    el = document.querySelector("div.postSearch");
    el.className = "revolver";
  }
};
```

There is a lot more to this page in production which is why some of the IDs etc don't make sure. I feel like using 'toggleClass' is a better idea for the myForm/postponed swap also. (I do this so hitting 'Go' again doesn't re-submit the form.

The codepen is located [here](http://codepen.io/dnorthrupva/pen/JRxRro) - If you notice when you hit 'go' you'll see a scroll bar periodically pop up. On smaller resolutions it happens, on 4K it happens. On the website it actually is causing the background image to 'shake' and snap around.

I'm not too familiar with transitions, but I followed the documents pretty specifically. I'll end up inverting it to get the search bar to go back since it kind of 'snaps' back right now. Would appreciate any advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the component is going out from document. Try by adding `overflow: hidden` to it's parent container. Please try this and let me know if this is helpful for you.

```js
function updateTransition() {
  var el = document.querySelector("div.revolver");
  if (el) {
    $('#myForm').addClass('postponed');
    $('#myForm').removeClass('myForm');

    el.className = "postSearch";
  } else {
    $('#myForm').addClass('myForm');
    $('#myForm').removeClass('postponed');
    el = document.querySelector("div.postSearch");
    el.className = "revolver";
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* temporary class */
}
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.postSearch {
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
  -moz-transform: rotate(1440deg);
  margin-left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overflow-hidden">
  <div class="revolver">
    <form id="myForm">
      <p class="inp-wrap search-wrap">
        <label for="charName" class="search-label grid-25">Find</label>
        <input type="search" name="charName" id="charName" class="grid-75" placeholder="e.g. Teodoro" />
      </p>
      <p class="inp-wrap cat-wrap">
        <label for="servers" class="grid-20">on</label>
        <select name="servers" id="servers" class="grid-80">
          <option>Thrall</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p class="inp-wrap submit-wrap">
        <button class="grid-100 btn" name="SubmitButton" onclick="updateTransition()" type="button">
          <span class="search-icon-container">
          <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span> GO!
        </button>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Scroll occurs because while form is spinning it goes out parent.

One possible solution is to add overflow: hidden for the time of animation.

```
body.transitionActive{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

js

```
[...]
    $('#myForm').addClass('postponed');
    $('body').addClass('transitionActive');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('body').removeClass('transitionActive');
    }, 3000);
    $('#myForm').removeClass('myForm');
[...]
```

See how it works here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALNLak

Comment: I didn't even think about using overflow like that - Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion only: Personally, I would never add `overflow: hidden;` to `<body></body>` for one module only.

Comment: But it is just for time of animation - it's removed after that